# Is there a way that two remote windows sessions sharing a mouse and a keyboard?

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft-virtual-pc, synergy, kvm-switch

The question is somewhat tricky to you unless you know about virtual desktop environment

Currently, my office is using several Ncomputing's L300 devices, thin clients, and sharing rss on the host computer

Each L300 device acts like a real pc except some limitations like the DUAL MONITORS support

So, I want to span a mouse and a keyboard attached to one device(one remote session) to other devices(another remote session) so that a user can use two monitors (two L300 devices) with one mouse and one keyboard as if he or she has dual monitors

Synergy or other software KVMs do not work since they need two physically different host computers

```
Monitor A                       Monitor B
   |                                 |
_________         _____       ____________
|L300 A  |--------|host|------|    L300 B |
_________         _____       ____________
______|_______                         |
Mouse/Keyboard---need a solution here---
```

Comment: Why not just use a dual-monitor workstation, and connect two remote desktop sessions, one in each monitor?

Comment: @RegEdit I have tens of workers who may ask me for a such set (a dual-monitor workstation lol) if I allow one person to have a dual monitor workstation haha

Answer (score 0):

How about http://www.synergy-project.org/ or Mouse without Borders ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460 ). I am not sure about your OS, the thin client support etc. but you can give these a try (Mouse without Borders is free).

/cd

Comment: The OP has already said this wont work.

Comment: @cdavid they both work fine on two different computers but on two remote sessions from the same machine